# Ravendb bulk insert with "Document Expiration"?

Tags: ravendb

How can i do to bulk insert with document expiration?

The doc files only say to add metadata "@expires" but only way to do that is over single insert mode and that method does not work on bulk insert

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/studio/database/settings/document-expiration

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/server/extensions/expiration#setting-the-document-expiration-time

Comment: Can you try to use the **Patch** operation and update multiple documents ? The metadata of the document can be accessed in a Patch operation (see how to access the metadata in this example: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/client-api/operations/patching/set-based#updating-a-collection-name

Comment: By Patch method worked fine thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the metadata for the stored entity.

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/client-api/bulk-insert/how-to-work-with-bulk-insert-operation#methods

Comment: Ok, but how do you generate the `IMetadataDictionary`?